# What’s the Difference Between on 'or' group condition twig

Tags: symfony, twig, conditional-statements

What’s the Difference Between

> {% if   (colorTab.about is empty )or (colorTab.services is empty )or
>                           (colorTab.annonces is empty) }

and

> {% if   (colorTab.about or colorTab.services or
>   colorTab.annonces) is empty }

Comment: For me the first one works fine but the second one doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that for the first statement any of the variable can be empty, as for the second statement, you actually can replace that statement with the following one

```
{% if (colorTab.about is empty) and (colorTab.services is empty) and (colorTab.annonces is empty) %}
```

That is because you have to substitute each variable first before the function `twig_is_empty` is called. Twig will compile the statement into the following `PHP` code

`if (twig_is_empty($var1 || $var2 || $var3) {`

Thus this will become either `if (twig_is_empty(true) {` or `if (twig_is_empty(false) {` on runtime. Meaning only a combination of 3 [non-empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues) values can return `true` for the function `twig_is_emtpy`

---

<kbd>vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php, line 1405</kbd>

```
function twig_test_empty($value) 
 {
  if ($value instanceof Countable) {
    return 0 == count($value);
  }

  return '' === $value || false === $value || null === $value || array() === $value;
}
```